# Automated printouts from a wireless printer

Tags: linux, printing, automation, latex

I have a wireless printer which is always on, and an always on fanless Linux server.

Looking at the mprinter project on Kickstarter I started to wonder if there is a way for me to  prepare an automated daily printout based on some settings.

Things to be printed could include

- weather forecast for my locations
- TODOs scheduled for that day
- a "quote of a day" or "word of the day"
- stats from Google Analytics for my site
- and many more …

I would set a printout at 6:15 every work day so its on my printer when I am already up, having a coffee.

While I know this can be done by combining the power of TeX, cron and a script language to manage the dynamic part of the PDF, I believe this is a use case someone might have already addressed.

How could I set that up?

Comment: @terdon Please don't take that rule too stricly. There is a specific task to solve here, and it's not a question in the vein of "Suggest me the best XYZ".

Answer (score 0):

***By no means is this the cleanest way of doing things.***
This is a general idea of what you could quickly hack together to achieve what you want to do.

#### Set up your printer

First and foremost, you want to get your printer working. CUPS does support wireless printers, so with a bit of luck and the right drivers you will be able to set that up. Refer to your server's distribution wiki / help pages for more information.

#### Get the data

You then want to get your data in plaintext. Google will help you find scripts that will do most the generic of the tasks that you need:

- [**Weather**](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/9832/plain-text-weather-on-command-line/)
- [**Quotes with `fortune`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix))

For other specific needs, you'll have to write them on your own:

- **TODOs** depend on what mechanism you already use to keep track of that
- **Google Analytics**. Unfortunately not accessible via command line browsers and I don't know anything about the Google Analytics API. I can only think of very ugly and unreliable ways of doing this so you will have to do some searching.

#### Hack your scripts together

We now have a bunch of scripts that work, but we need to put all that data together. For most of my hackjobs I go with `Python`. Not only is it easy to pick up and use, you can even "embed" other scripts into it a python file and grab their input:

> from os import popen
>
> script='''ps aux;
>    echo;
>    free -h'''
>
> output=popen(script).read()

Not the best idea, but this way you don't **have** to re-write complex functions that are already available to you.

#### Formatting

HTML is easy to learn and prettify. Google to the rescue again: [Python and HTML](http://python.about.com/od/cgiformswithpython/ss/pycgitut2_all.htm). Join the data we have with HTML, add a few lines of [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS) to define what your page will look like (fonts, colors, layouts etc) and have python write all this into a file.

#### Print your document

1. Save your script on your server and test it out. Jump to [`Can I print html files from the command-line?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286583/can-i-print-html-files-with-images-css-from-the-command-line) to do some test printing.
2. Add a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)job that will run your script every morning at the desired time.
3. Add coffee.

Paper is a precious resource; I would have my webserver serve this file and read it on my tablet, phone, or laptop.